# Разный контент на страницах ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

Доброго времени суток.
C адаптером все понятно, а можно ли на страницах ViewPager отобразить разное содержимое, то есть разные Layout ? Поддержите рабочим примером, пожалуйста!

Comment: а в чем проблема то? добавляете вместо одинаковых элементов разные, вот и все дела.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если коротко, то разный контент(разные layout) можно организовать с помощью  `Fragment`'ов , т.е. создаете `N-ое` количество фрагментов:

**FirstFragment.java**

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    // Store instance variables
    private String title;
    private int page;

    // newInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments
    public static FirstFragment newInstance(int page, String title) {
        FirstFragment fragmentFirst = new FirstFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("someInt", page);
        args.putString("someTitle", title);
        fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
        return fragmentFirst;
    }

    // Store instance variables based on arguments passed
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        page = getArguments().getInt("someInt", 0);
        title = getArguments().getString("someTitle");
    }

    // Inflate the view for the fragment based on layout XML
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        TextView tvLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvLabel);
        tvLabel.setText(page + " -- " + title);
        return view;
    }
}
```

и далее в адаптере эти фрагменты отображаются:

```
public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        // Returns total number of pages
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }

        // Returns the fragment to display for that page
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment
                return FirstFragment.newInstance(0, "Page # 1");
            case 1: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment different title
                return FirstFragment.newInstance(1, "Page # 2");
            case 2: // Fragment # 1 - This will show SecondFragment
                return SecondFragment.newInstance(2, "Page # 3");
            default:
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Returns the page title for the top indicator
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Page " + position;
        }

    }
```

Это примитивный пример взятый с другого примера, его при необходимости можно модифицировать. На пример, создать в адаптере список фрагментов, накидать туда нужное количество фрагментов и в методе доставать.

```
   @Override
   public Fragment getItem(int position) {
       return fragmentsList.get(position);
   }
```